# Creating multiple child processes running parallel

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I am new to this child parent processes. And id like to create a Master and 3 slaves. Are those the same thing? If I create 3 childs would it be like 3 slaves? My other question will be I already created 3 childs. But I am strongly believing that these child processes  are not running parallel. I have to make them run parallel. I believe this for loop is not allowing it? How other way can i implement three slaves running parallel and at random order they are finishing their jobs? The way i imlpemented it, always goes like slave 1 finished, then slave 2 finished. But my professor asks me that they should be able to finish at random order. I think my codes child processes creates the other child when the previous childs code is done.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){

    pid_t slave = fork();
    if (slave==0) /* only execute this if child */
        {
                std::cout << "Slave " << i+1 << ": ";

                switch(i+1){
                    case 1 :
                            std::cout << "Project statistics" << std::endl; 
                        break;
                    case 2 :
                            std::cout << "Midterm statistics" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    case 3 :
                            std::cout << "Final statistics" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    default :
                            std::cout << "Something Went Wrong" << std::endl;
                }           

                foo("Child");
                std::cout << "Slave " << i+1 << ": Done" << std::endl;
                exit(0);

        }
        wait(&status);  /* only the parent waits */
```

}

Comment: I have to make them run parallel....that is scheduler's job

Comment: is there any specific order that you are looking to impose?

Comment: No what i meant was. The proceses should run parallel. If the first processes' job is more then the second one and third one then second and third process should finish first. Then the first one , after finishing it's job, should finish. It should only be depended on the work load. In this for loop i believ it only allows to create the second process when the first process is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `wait(&status)` for it to work in parallel (this will have for the child before spawning another child). Then add to the end another loop to fetch the status.

i.e. the code should be

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   pid_t slave = fork();
   if (slave==0) /* only execute this if child */
   {
     std::cout << "Slave " << i+1 << ": ";

     switch (i+1) {
       case 1 :
         std::cout << "Project statistics" << std::endl; 
         break;
       case 2 :
         std::cout << "Midterm statistics" << std::endl;
         break;
       case 3 :
         std::cout << "Final statistics" << std::endl;
         break;
       default :
         std::cout << "Something Went Wrong" << std::endl;
     }           
     foo("Child");
     std::cout << "Slave " << i+1 << ": Done" << std::endl;
     exit(0);
   }
 }
 for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    wait(&status);
 }
```

Comment: I tried that but it just does the work in the reverse order. instead of one cout on one process i wrote 4 couts. So the output is lave 3: Final statistics
Final statistics
Final statistics
Final statistics
I am a Child  My pid is: 70967 my Parent's pid: 70964
Slave 3: Done
Slave 2: Midterm statistics
Midterm statistics
Midterm statistics
Midterm statistics
I am a Child  My pid is: 70966 my Parent's pid: 70964
Slave 2: Done
Slave 1: Project statistics
Project statistics
Project statistics
Project statistics
I am a Child  My pid is: 70965 my Parent's pid: 70964
Slave 1: Done
Master: Finish

Comment: It is working in parallel - just that the scheduler has given each child enough time to complete before yielding. Try getting the child to do something not so trivial

Comment: Oh ok then. Now i got your point. Thank you. But what about the master slave relation? The thing that we implement is one master and 3 slaves? or one parent process and 3 child process?